# Android, Animate just parent view, not child?

Tags: android, animation

I have a `FrameLayout` in which there is a `TextView`. I want to animate `FrameLayout` using `ScaleAnimation` but I want my `TextView` be fix. I searched but couldn't find a solution. How can I do it?
Here there is an example of what I want:

[A gif showing what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zx6O6.gif)

Comment: Why do you need to animate the parent layout anyway?

I think what you're trying to achieve is impossible, try a different approach like overlapping views -- whereas there is an another view for background and textview on the foreground?

Comment: I added a gif to show what I want to make @dr3k

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, scale up the parent while scaling down the view itself! From the user's perspective, the view is not changing. Also, don't use `Scale Animation` or any other related class. use `PropertyAnimations` instead. This is more flexible, especially in your case that you want to change the properties (scaleX, scaleY) of more than one view.